# Getting SSL error with Python on one virtual machine profile but not another

Tags: python, ssl, conda

So basically I have a windows virtual machine that is running Anaconda, which has Python 3.8 installed. Both profiles share this installation on the VM, in the conda environment I have installed `certifi` which makes it work perfectly for User 1, but when I run the same conda environment for User 2 I get the following error:

```
(Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

Any ideas as to why one user running the same script in the same environment wouldn't have the same result? I can provide more if necessary. Just not sure what I could give.

Comment: Check out the environment where these VM run in. Antivirus products (like ESET but likely others too) are known for intercepting TLS connections in order to analyze the traffic for malware. This can also affect traffic from VM. SSL interception changes the CA of from a trusted one to one only locally trusted by the VM host though and this will make certificate validation inside the VM fail.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for the reply, is disabling Windows Defender something to try? I tried it to no avail. Not sure what else I could do, both profiles share the same antivirus

Comment: Anything what is different between the VM hosts might be a problem. And also the environment of the VM host itself, i.e. maybe one is behind a corporate firewall while the other isn't. The best would likely to find out which the served certificate chain is in the first place from inside the VM, like trying with [openssl s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-s_client.html).

Comment: I tried turning off the firewall and nothing changed. Could you explain that openssl command? I just ran it and received some errors: `6828:error:0200274D:system library:connect:reason(1869):crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:110:
6828:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:111:
6828:error:0200274D:system library:connect:reason(1869):crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:110:
6828:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:crypto\bio\b_sock2.c:111:
connect:errno=0`

Comment: I assume I need to use it to attempt to connect to a website?

Comment: You need to provide host and port, i.e. `openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443`   for access to  `https://example.com`.

Comment: Getting the same response for both profiles oddly: `CONNECTED(00000154)
depth=0 CN = ***
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = ***
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1`

Comment: There is more output. The main question is if both instances get the same certificate and see the same certificate chain. As example see https://pastebin.com/mKEsWdmq - the chain is in lines 10..14 and the server certificate in lines 17..69

Comment: Yup I put both outputs in text-compare.com and they are identical, not sure what to do. I feel like there's something im missing thats simple

Comment: The only explanation I have then is that the two VM have not exactly the same conda environment or don't run the same code, contrary to your claim.

Comment: Yea that's the only thing I can think of, I'm going to literally paste the whole folder from the working env

Comment: I tried it outside the environment, using a separate Python installation for each profile. And the problem persists, would this mean that it's something to do with the profile then?

Comment: Looks like I fixed it, I downloaded the chain certificate and copy and pasted it to the end of `cacert` file that under my `certifi` python installation. No idea why it's not required for both profiles but w.e, thank you!